# Facebook | Can't get profiles that are mentioned in a facebook profile post

Tags: facebook, post, profile

I have an App that needs to query a users's profile post.

For any post, I'm trying to figure out:

- the number of people (profiles) mentioned and
- the names of the people (profiles) mentioned

Assume the user has already given the App access to view their profile data.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post

According to the documentation, if a user mentions 2 profiles, say "Friend1" and "Friend2" then I should be able to get back a response that includes the field:

[image: Response to query]

which has some profile information for "Friend1" and "Friend2".

The problem I'm having is given the `GET` query

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/10207722160149556_10207755501343065
```

I get the response:

```
{:created_time "2015-11-08T09:29:54+0000", :message "Friend1 Friend2 testing again sorry just ignore", :id "10207722160149556_10207755501343065"}
```

I don't get a `to` field or for that matter a bunch of other information?

Does anyone know how I can get back what is listed in the documentation as what I should be getting?

Any help would be appreciated

In case this helps, these are the permissions I'm currently requesting:

```
["user_photos" "user_friends" "publish_actions"
 "user_posts" "user_likes" "user_relationships"
 "user_about_me" "email" "public_profile"
 "user_tagged_places"]
```

Kind regards, 
Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, bad case of not reading the documentation and a library that I was using that got in the way.

I have to include a "field" query param to specify what I want returned.

After that and validating with a curl call I can get the information I need.